# How to reproject spatial files in the GDAL shell?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, wgs84

I have multiple spatial files that need to be reprojected for GCS WGS84.

How do I reproject in the GDAL shell?

Which command should I use ?

Comment: Is you data vector, raster or a mixture of both? There is a post https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/recipes/gdal-reproject which describes the different approaches required for vector and raster files. Are you trying to script this, either in CMD BAT file or python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `gdalwarp` for raster data:

From the `gdalwarp` [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html):

> **gdalwarp**
>
> Image reprojection and warping utility
>
> **Description**
>
> The gdalwarp utility is an image mosaicing, **reprojection** and warping
>   utility. The program can reproject to any supported projection, and
>   can also apply GCPs stored with the image if the image is “raw” with
>   control information.

And `ogr2ogr` for vector data:

From the `ogr2ogr` [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html):

> **ogr2ogr**
>
> Converts simple features data between file formats.
>
> **Description**
>
> ogr2ogr can be used to convert simple features data between file
>   formats. It can also perform various operations during the process,
>   such as spatial or attribute selection, reducing the set of
>   attributes, setting the output coordinate system or even **reprojecting the features during translation**.